# DataBinding in winforms : Update even though I click "Cancel"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a problem with DataBinding in Winforms, Even though I click "Cancel" on the form, the objecte is updated.

I've set the property "DialogResult" of the Ok button to "OK", of the Cancel button to "Cancel", also, I've set the properties "AccesptButton" and "CancelButton" of the form to bnOk and bnCancel.

Here is my code :

**Model :**

```
private string code;
public string Code
{
     get { return code; }
     set { SetPropertyValue<string>("Code", ref code, value); }
}

private string libelle;
public string Libelle
{
     get { return libelle; }
     set { SetPropertyValue<string>("Libelle", ref libelle, value); }
}
```

**UI :**

```
public FamilleTiers CurrentFamilleTiers { get; set; }
private void FamilleTiersForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     txCode.DataBindings.Add("Text", CurrentFamilleTiers, "Code");
     txLibelle.DataBindings.Add("Text", CurrentFamilleTiers, "Libelle");
}
```

**Edit function :**

```
public static void EditFamilleTiers(FamilleTiers selectedFamilleTiers)
{
   using (FamilleTiersForm form = new FamilleTiersForm() { CurrentFamilleTiers =  selectedFamilleTiers, Text = selectedFamilleTiers.Libelle })
   {
         if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
             form.CurrentFamilleTiers.Save();
         }
   }
}
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click cancel on a form data binding does not revert you need to keep a backup copy of the values and if they change replace the new values with the original values. .Net does not know what your wanting to do.

Comment: Thank you, it's helpful.
Here's what I did : Set the DataSourceUpdateMode of the DataBinding to Never, and if the user click on OK, I update the object properties.

Comment: That is a solution which I am glad it works for you but is there a point to using data binding then ?

Comment: The advantage here, is that I'm not forced to set the controls properties (ex : "Text" or "EditValue") after getting the selected object. Or is there an other solution ?

Comment: No sounds good just wanted to make sure I understood and wasn't givng you a bad solution :)